# WHen I delete products andvariations via VBO some are still left

Tags: commerce

I delete all my products and also the variations were deleted at the same time

but still after VBO delete under commerce/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fcommerce%252Fproducts

some products are still left

why? I am attaching the image, there are empty products without variations inside that I cant delete

why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Basic question: have you clear all caches?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal Commerce there are products and product displays. Did you delete the products and perhaps these are the remaining displays, which aren't displaying properly because you deleted the products?

Comment: I know there are products and product displays, I deleted all products and all displays were deleted also, BUT when I go to mydomain.com/products i still see these empty shells of products without product displays inside, so why are they not listed under products in the admin section of drupal? There are no ptroducts there under admin/commerce/products  but still they exist if I go to /products

Comment: these empty shells are in fact displays that can be seen on mywebsite.com/products but cant be seen under admin/commerce/products so I am not sure what is this happening, i can click on it and edit it and try to click delete button at the right bottom edge but it says ass display before, and after i add display, i can delete the display alltogether, but i have like 50 of those so it will take me long time to manually delete them, why is this happening at all?

Comment: if I go into category for that product that are nowhere to be seen, I see pager with three pages at the bottom but no products, so there must be something there, in database that was not deleted here is the error code I get it I visit mywebsite.com/termname  Warning: uasort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in node_view_multiple() (line 2679 of /home/wwwd/public_html/commerce/modules/node/node.module).